# Is there a paragon path or epic path that could replace the 3E era Alienist class?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm looking at doing some work with an older D&D setting that relies on the Alienist class from the 3E+ rules. Is there an official alternative that would retain the general intent/theme and power set of this class in the 4E rules?

Comment: Not sure about power set, but for theme a Warlock is an Alienist just by a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psionic Power contains Alienist as a paragon path for Psion from Player's Handbook 3.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're looking for the whole Lovecraftian researcher flavor the Alienist had, there's the Master of the Starry Night paragon path, for star-pact Warlocks (from Arcane Power, I think).  I doubt it's very similar mechanically, though.